# save/reuse doc2vec based model for further predictions

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gensim

I have been following the following example for using doc2vec for text classification:

https://github.com/susanli2016/NLP-with-Python/blob/master/Text%20Classification%20model%20selection.ipynb

I ran this notebook on my datasets and want to apply one of the doc2vec models to a 3rd dataset (eg, the overall dataset the test/train model was built on).  I tried:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.post, df.tags, random_state=0, test_size=0.3)
X_train = label_sentences(X_train, 'Train')
X_test = label_sentences(X_test, 'Test')

#added
big_text = label_sentences(big_text, 'Test') #big_text = larger dataframe

#old
#all_data = X_train + X_test

#new
all_data = X_train + X_test + big_text
```

1 - this is not really practical for applied purposes.  The data that one wants to predict might not be available at the time of train/testing.

2 - the model performance decreased as a result

So how can I save once of the models and applying to a completely different dataset?  It would seems that I would need to update the doc2vec model with docs of the other dataset as well.

Comment: You should look at serialization using the Pickle module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). This will let you save any Python object to a file that you can later on reload using the same module.

Comment: @Paupaulaz - Thanks.  I am familiar with this for non-text models.  In this case I have a doc2Vec model and a predictive model.  I think I can pickle the predictive model but I'm not sure how/if I should update doc2vec on the unseen data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gensim `Doc2Vec` model may be saved and loaded using the `.save(filepath)` & `.load(filepath)` methods. (Using these native-to-gensim methods will work on larger models than plain Python pickling can support, and more-efficiently store some of the larger internal arrays as separate files. (If moving the saved model, be sure to keep this subsidiary files alongside the main file that's at exactly the `filepath` location.)

A previously-trained `Doc2Vec` model can generate doc-vectors for new texts via the `.infer_vector(list_of_words)` method.

Note that the `list_of_words` provided to this method should have been preprocessed/tokenized exactly the same as the training data – and any words that weren't present (or sufficiently `min_count` frequent) in the training data will be ignored. (At the extreme, this means if you pass in a `list_of_words` with no recognized words, all words will be ignored, and you'll get back a randomly-initialized but completely-unimproved-by-inference vector.)

Still, if you're re-evaulating or re-training the downstream predictive models on new data from some new domain, you'd often want to re-train the `Doc2Vec` stage as well, with all available data, so that it has a chance to learn new words from new usage contexts. (It's mainly when your training data was extensive & representative, and your new data comes in incrementally and without major shifts in vocabulary/usage/domain, that you'd want to rely on `.infer_vector()`.)

Comment: In the example I was following they trained the doc2vec model on both training/test data.  So rather it should have been just the train data and infer_vector() used with test (and future uses)?

Comment: Not necessarily. As an unsupervised method that isn't necessarily peeking at desired outcomes/labels during, it can be defensible to train `Doc2Vec` models on all available data, including unlabeled or labels-held-back data. But when you start tuning its parameters based on desired results from some downstream process, you may need to hold things back to get a more reliable estimate of its predictive power. But then you might include as much as possible before production deployment. So without seeing their example, & knowing more about your processes & goals, I can't say what "should" be done.